# SSH button in Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Clicking on the SSH button in Google Compute Engine immediately closes the window after opening the window for a moment.
Having the issue in Latest Chrome and Edge on Windows 10.
Any help, please..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue, Have you tried to reproduce using Incognito window?
If you still observe issues, try capturing HAR while SSHing into instance and upload the HAR to check browser interaction with the GCP site. Instructions on how to capture HAR is documented [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/)